# Energy consumption drops after closing/opening lid on a notebook with both Nvidia and Intel graphics running Windows 10

Tags: windows, laptop, power-management, lid, nvidia

My notebook (Lenovo Z710) has an Intel i7-4800MQ and an Nvidia GT 745M, so it basically has two graphics adapters. It is running Windows 10, using the latest drivers (I tried, however, older ones, too).

During normal office work or browsing, the Nvidia hardware should not be active at all, to save energy.

Now I noticed, that after waking the Notebook from standby (S3) mode, it has a higher energy consumption. If I then close the lid and re-open it, it drops by ~10 watts. And stays there. I configured Windows to not do anything when closing the lid (normal behavior would be standby mode). The notebook runs 10 degrees Celsius cooler afterwards!

Starting hardware detection in the device manager has the same effect. Disabling and then enabling the Nvidia hardware has the same effect. Re-starting the "NVIDIA Display Container LS" service has the same effect, too.

So I suspect it really is the Nvidia card which causes this. The CPU does not clock lower nor does the CPU load drop. So what else could it be?

The question is, what can I do so my notebook wakes up properly with a low energy consumption in the first place (without me closing/re-opening the lid)? I already tried several Nvidia drivers.